# How to combine 2 mysql queries

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have the following 2 queries.

```
Query 1 : 
select distinct(thread_id) from records where client_name='MyClient'

Query 2 :
select max(thread_no) from records 
where thread_id='loop_result_from_above_query' AND action='Reviewed'
```

Is it possible to combine them into a single query ?

The second query is run on every result of the first query.

### Thank you.

See attached image of a small snippet of mysql records.
[image]

I need a single mysql query to output only records which have action="MyAction" as the latest records for a given set of thread_ids. In the sample data set : record with Sr: 7201

I hope this helps in helping me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  client_name, thread_id, MAX(thread_no) max_thread
FROM    records
WHERE   action='Reviewed' AND client_name='MyClient'
GROUP   BY client_name, thread_id
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    records a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  thread_id, max(sr) max_sr
            FROM    records
            GROUP   BY thread_id
        ) b ON a.thread_id = b.thread_id AND
                a.sr = b.max_sr
WHERE   a.action = 'MyAction'
```

Comment: in you first statement you said, `action='Reviewed'` bit now it's `action='MyAction'` how can we sort it? and why is the final result only `7201`?

Comment: My bad regarding confusion between 'Reviewed' & 'MyAction'.

Comment: My bad regarding confusion between 'Reviewed' & 'MyAction'. Pls consider 'MyAction as required 'action' for this data set. I need only rows where highest thread_no for every thread_id has action='MyAction'. Given dataset has  2 thread_ids '1111111111' & '2222222222'. Each of these have 1 or more thread_no. The highest thread_no for thread_id = 1111111111 is '2' whose action != 'MyAction'. Hence this record does not qualify. The highest thread_no for thread_id 222222222 is '3' whose action='MyAction' which qualifies as the desired output. I hope I have been able to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SELF JOIN, but it is not advisable and will impact your query performance. Please check below query for your reference

```
SELECT DISTINCT r1.thread_id, MAX(r2.thread_no) from records r1 LEFT JOIN records r2 ON r2.thread_id=r1.thread_id WHERE r1.client_name='MyClient' AND r2.action='Reviewed'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.maxthreadid, 
       b.maxthreadno 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT( thread_id ) AS MaxThreadId 
        FROM   records 
        WHERE  client_name = 'MyClient') a 
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT Max(thread_no) AS MaxThreadNo 
                   FROM   records 
                   WHERE  thread_id = 'loop_result_from_above_query' 
                          AND action = 'Reviewed') b
```

Comment: Too complex for my caliber... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT Row_number() 
                 OVER ( 
                   partition BY thread_id 
                   ORDER BY thread_no)      no, 
               Max(thread_no) 
                 OVER( 
                   partition BY thread_id ) Maxthread_no, 
               thread_id, 
               action, 
               client_name 
        FROM   records
        Where client_name = 'MyClient') AS T1 
WHERE  no = 1 
       AND action = 'Reviewed'
```

Comment: This totally went over my head.